# Call to a member function tasks() on null on laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Let me explain with a couple of word my problem.
On my controller i have this line:

```
$tasks = $student->group->tasks()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->withPivot('id')->get();
```

This works for existing users, but when i try to create new ones i receive

`Call to a member function tasks() on null`

Can i with something like this or what do you suggest ?

```
if(!is_null($tasks))
    $tasks = $student->group->tasks()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->withPivot('id')->get();
}
```

This i my show function on controller

```
public function show(){
    $user = Auth::user();

    if(!$user)
        return redirect('/')->withErrors(config('constants.NA'));

    $countries = Country::all()->lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
    $profile = $user->profile;
  $student = $profile->student;

  // Tasks showed on students profile
  if ($student->group) {
      $tasks = $student->group->tasks()
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->withPivot('id')
          ->get();
  }
  // Classmates
  if ($student->group) {
      $classmates = $student->group->students()
      ->where('id', '!=', $student->id)
      ->get();

  }

  // Activated books
  $books = Auth::user()->books()->orderBy('grade_id', 'asc')->get();


  if(!is_null($student->group))
    $iTasks = $student->group->tasks->count();
  else {
    $iTasks = 0;
  }

  $iTodos = $user->todos->count();

    return view('student.profile.show',compact('user','profile', 'countries', 'iTasks', 'iTodos', 'tasks', 'classmates', 'books'));
}
```

This is my show view, for the tasks

```
<div class="tab-pane <?php if(isset($tab) && $tab == 'timeline'): ?> active <?php endif; ?>" id="timeline">
                        @if($tasks->count())
                          <div class="timeline">
                            @foreach($tasks as $task)
                              <!-- TIMELINE ITEM -->
                              <div class="timeline-item">
                                <div class="timeline-badge">
                                  <div class="timeline-icon">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-clipboard-text font-red-intense"></i>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                  <div class="timeline-body-arrow"> </div>
                                  <div class="timeline-body-head">
                                    <div class="timeline-body-head-caption">
                                      <span class="timeline-body-title font-blue-madison">
                                        {{ $task->professor->profile->user->name }}
                                      </span>
                                      <span class="timeline-body-time font-grey-cascade">ju ca caktuar një <a href="/student/tasks" class="font-red sbold">detyrë</a> të re.</span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="timeline-body-content">
                                    <span class="font-grey-cascade">
                                      {{ $task->pivot->comment }}
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                  <hr>
                                  Lenda: <span class="timeline-body-time font-grey-cascade sbold">{{ $task->subject->name }}</span>
                                  <div class="pull-right">
                                    Krijuar më: <span class="timeline-body-time font-grey-cascade sbold">{{ $task->created_at->format(Config::get('klasaime.date_format')) }}</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- END TIMELINE ITEM -->
                            @endforeach
                          </div>
                        @else
                          <div class="alert">
                            Ju nuk keni asnje detyrë të caktuar!
                          </div>
                        @endif
                      </div>
```

Comment: where is tasks function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you haven't added the student to a group yet, or that somehow hasn't been persisted. If you have added the student to a group after creating and saving the student, try this:

```
$student->load('group')
```

Before running:

```
$tasks = $student->group->tasks()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->withPivot('id')->get();
```

I'll need to see more of your code to give a more accurate answer. But the error you're getting is related to the `->group`, of your student, not your student itself.

Comment: Yes, every user registering for the first time should select their group and then after, on his profile page it will be listed all the tasks regarding that group.

Like i said before, this only happens with new users because by default the group is null.

Now, both of them are stored on the show blade on student profile, so first i want to go to add that new group for the students, but then this error occurs, by not letting me to complete the user info:

Call to a member function tasks() on null

Comment: Alright can you please update your question with the full method of your controller that is called when the user is created? Should be easy enough to see then :-) I think I know what the cause is, but need to see your code to be sure.

Comment: I have, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple check to see if the group exists and then carry on with whatever action you need to perform.

```
// controller
$tasks = null;

if ($student->group) {
    $tasks = $student->group->tasks()
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->withPivot('id')
        ->get();
}

// view
@if($tasks)
    {{ $tasks->id }}
@else
    No tasks found
@endif
```

**Edit** : In your controller add `$tasks = null;` and `$classmates = null;` at top. And in your view change `@if($tasks->count())` to `@if($tasks)`. I'm not sure where your use the classmates variable, but add a check to see if it's null before you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after doing like you said now i receive:

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\klasaime\resources\views\student\profile\show.blade.php)

on storage/framework/views/

Comment: @Nibla that was just a pseudo code. The actual code should depend on how you're gonna use the variable. Post your view code and your full controller logic so that we can help you better.

Comment: I have, please check

Comment: @Nibla updated my answer. You're not setting the default values when group doesn't exist and not performing a null check in the view.

Comment: now i receive this error  'Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/dev.klasaime.com/resources/views/student/profile/show.blade.php)'